# Windows console app opens in new console instead of the same console

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, console

I do have a Windows console application, written in C++ and compile with the console subsystem but when started from the command line, it does open a new window instead of reusing the same console window.

It seems that the cause is that executable has a manifest that requires admin privledges in order to run.

This was added in order to be able to properly read some keys form HKLM.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it have a manifest that says it must run as admin, by any chance? Does the behavior change if you run it from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: how do you run your exe from bat? using name or using call command ?

Comment: You are right, this has the manifest to run as Admin. This was needed in order to be able to read the HKLM without virtualization. The same executable is made to run as a service but it can also run as a console app. I do have to *read* some settings from HKLM, maybe even writing (not sure). Without this, I was surprised to read nothing from the HKLM.

Comment: Start your console to run the program with admin permissions...

Comment: I already did this and it's ok, I could even accept it as an answer. Unless someone could also provide a solution regarding preventing windows from virtualising the HKLM entries of this app, and in this case I could disable the require Admin privs from the manifest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to specify a `requestedExecutionLevel` of `requireAdministrator` in the application manifest in order to make it able to read from HKLM without virtualization.

You do not need to elevate in order to read from HKLM. And so long as your process has an application manifest that specifies `requestedExecutionLevel` then it will not be virtualized. The conclusion therefore is that you need to specify a `requestedExecutionLevel` of `asInvoker`.

Details of registry virtualization can be found in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884.aspx#Registry_Virtualization_Scope).